# Continuous functions with a certain condition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

What is the class of continuous functions $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which satisfy

$f(x)-f(y)\in\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $x-y\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: No, $f(x) = x$ satisfies it too.

Comment: In fact, constant functions do *not* satisfy this condition.

Comment: Sorry, I meant multiples of $x$... :)

Comment: Note that $f(x)=\pi+\frac23x$ is ok, but $f(x)=\frac23+\pi x$ is not.

Comment: So, the guess is $f(x)=a+rx$ for some $a\in\Bbb R$ and $r\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$. Isn't it?

Comment: @mrf With $f:x\mapsto|x|$, $x=\pi$ and $y=-\pi$, $f(x)-f(y)=0\in\mathbb Q$ but $x-y=2\pi\notin\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @SebastienB, I forgot about 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $t$ be a rational number. Consider the function $g(x)=f(x+t)-f(x)$. Then $g$
is continuous also and takes values only in $\mathbb Q$, so $g$ is constant.
It follows that $g(x)=g(0)=f(t)-f(0)=c(t)$.

So we have

$$
f(x+t)=f(x)+c(t) \tag{1}
$$

for any real $x$ and rational $t$. Then $c$ is certainly linear, so there is
an $r\in {\mathbb Q}$ such that $c(t)=rt$ for any rational $t$. So $f(t)=f(0)+rt$
by taking $x=0$ in $1$.

The continuity of $f$ then implies that $f(t)=f(0)+rt$ for all $t$. Conversely,
functions of this form are clearly solutions.

**UPDATE**  (in answer to a comment) : here is a more detailed explanation
 of why $c$ is linear.

We have $c(t_1+t_2)=f(t_1+t_2)-f(0)$ (take $x=0$ in (1)), and
$c(t_1)=f(t_1)-f(0)$ (take $x=0$ in (1)), 
$c(t_2)=f(t_1+t_2)-f(t_1)$ (take $x=t_1$ in (1)). So
$c(t_1+t_2)=c(t_1)+c(t_2)$.

Comment: "Then $c$ is certainly linear." Is it obvious?

Comment: @Sebastien B: Consider $f(x+t_1+t_2)$.

Comment: What about $f:x\mapsto x$ if $x\leq 0$ and $x\mapsto 2x$ if $x\geq 0$ (in the spirit of the attempt of mrf).

Comment: @SebastienB : please read my update.

Comment: My attempt also fails with $x=-\sqrt{2}$ and $y=2-\sqrt{2}$. So I take it back.

Comment: Ok, I got it. To get the $\mathbb Q$-linearity of $c$ you then use that for $p\in\mathbb Z$, $q\in\mathbb N$ and $r\in\mathbb Q$, $c(r\,q \,p/q )=q\,c(r\,p/q )$ hence $c(r\,p/q )=c(rp )/q=p/q\, c(r)$.

Comment: In fact $x-y \in \mathbb Q \implies f(x)-f(y) \in \mathbb Q$ is enough, the other implication only excludes constant functions and is somewhat unpleasant, because without it the set of functions forms a vector space.

Comment: So, finally, my guess was right :)